# Update rows set uniqe values from another table MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables for example. First contains generated serials for details. The second contains produced datails. I need to insert unique serial numbers to the second.

**T1**

| t1.ID | t1.OBJ_TYPE | t1.OBJ_SERIAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | DRW157001 |
| 2 | 5 | DRW157002 |
| 3 | 5 | DRW157003 |
| 4 | 5 | DRW157004 |
| 5 | 5 | DRW157005 |
| 6 | 5 | DRW157006 |

**T2**

| t2.ID | t2.DETAIL_TYPE | t2.DETAIL_SERIAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | DRW157001 |
| 2 | 5 | DRW157005 |
| 3 | 5 | **NULL** |
| 4 | 5 | **NULL** |
| 5 | 5 | **NULL** |
| 6 | 5 | **NULL** |

Is it possible to to make like this after update?

**Result**

| t2.ID | t2.DETAIL_TYPE | t2.DETAIL_SERIAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | DRW157001 |
| 2 | 5 | DRW157005 |
| 3 | 5 | **DRW157002** |
| 4 | 5 | **DRW157003** |
| 5 | 5 | **DRW157004** |
| 6 | 5 | **DRW157006** |

SQL query

`UPDATE t2, t1 SET t2.DETAIL_SERIAL = (SELECT t1.OBJ_SERIAL FROM t1 LIMIT 1 ) WHERE t1.OBJ_TYPE = t2.DETAIL_TYPE`

Comment: Clarify which version of MySQL you're using

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is possible using `JOIN` in `UPDATE` as follows:

```
UPDATE t2 
 INNER JOIN 
(SELECT T2ID, OBJ_SERIAL 
   FROM (SELECT T1.*, T2.ID T2ID, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T1.ID) AS T1RN,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T2.ID) AS T2RN
           FROM T1 JOIN T2 ON T1.OBJ_TYPE = T2.DETAIL_TYPE
          WHERE T2.DETAIL_SERIAL IS NULL
            AND NOT EXISTS 
                (SELECT 1 FROM T2 T22 
                  WHERE T1.OBJ_TYPE = T22.DETAIL_TYPE
                    AND T22.DETAIL_SERIAL = T1.OBJ_SERIAL 
                 )
        ) T 
  WHERE T1RN = T2RN) T
 SET T2.DETAIL_SERIAL = T.OBJ_SERIAL 
 WHERE T2.ID = T.T2ID
```

Comment: OK. Thank you!. I understand meaning of this query, but it is not working. It is an error near '(ORDER BY T1.ID) AS T1RN,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T2.ID) AS T2RN'

Answer (score 0):

Now i have that code and it's works for me.

```sql
SET @i := 0;
SET @j := 0;

UPDATE t2 DST LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT TD1.RNT1, TD1.OBJ_SERIAL, TD2.IDX, TD2.RNT2, TD2.DETAIL_SERIAL FROM 
    (
        SELECT @i := @i + 1 AS RNT1, TSRC1.OBJ_SERIAL FROM t1 TSRC1 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM t2 TSH1 WHERE TSRC1.OBJ_SERIAL = TSH1.DETAIL_SERIAL AND )
    ) TD1 
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT @j := @j + 1 AS RNT2, TSRC2.ID IDX, TSRC2.DETAIL_SERIAL FROM t2 TSRC2 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t1 TSH2 WHERE TSRC2.DETAIL_SERIAL = TSH2.OBJ_SERIAL) AND TSRC2.DETAIL_SERIAL IS NULL
    ) TD2 
    ON TD1.RNT1 = TD2.RNT2 AND TD1.OBJ_TYPE = TD2.DETAIL_TYPE
) TD3 
ON DST.ID = TD3.IDX 
SET DST.DETAIL_SERIAL = TD3.OBJ_SERIAL
WHERE TD3.IDX IS NOT NULL;
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

This is complicated.  The idea is to do the following:

1. Enumerate the rows in `t2` where `detail_serial` is `NULL`.
2. Enumerate the rows in `t1` where `obj_serial` is not being used in `t2`.
3. Join together for the `update`.

What makes this a bit more complicated, is that (1) requires an additional `join` (to `tt2` in the below query):

```
update t2 join
       (select t2.*,
               row_number() over (order by t2.id) as seqnum
        from t2
        where t2.DETAIL_SERIAL is null
       ) tt2
       on t2.id = tt2.id join
       (select t1.*,
               row_number() over (order by t1.id) as seqnum
        from t1
        where not exists (select 1
                          from t2
                          where t2.DETAIL_SERIAL = t1.OBJ_SERIAL
                         )
       ) t1
       on t1.seqnum = tt2.seqnum
    set t2.DETAIL_SERIAL = t1.OBJ_SERIAL;
```

I'm not quite sure where `obj_type` fits in.  However, if it also needs to match, then include it in the `not exists` subquery and in the final join.  Or perhaps you just want to filter on the value.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4023dfe87a2cbcdd5cbaa700400c36f7) is a db<>fiddle.